# Numerical integral with a weakly singular kernel with a satisfactory precision

Tags: quadrature, numerics, integration

I am working on a numerical method for time fractional PDE. One problem is that I must compute a numerical integral of the following form:

$$
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{t_m} (t_m-s)^{-\beta}f(s)ds
\end{equation}
$$

where $t_m$ and $0<\beta<1$ are constants. Noting that the integral has a weakly singular kernel, so classical quadrature, such as Gaussian quadrature, will invalid for the singularity of $(t_m-s)^{-\beta}$ at $s=t_m$. So my question is how to compute this kind of integral numerically with a given precision (because I need a high precision when computing the convergence ratio)?

**My try:**

I have deduced the Gaussian quadrature with the kernel of $(t_m-s)^{-\beta}$ which have a highest algebraic accuracy. But the formula is too complex so that when I compute the coefficients and nodes MATLAB loss precision which result in a bad precision.

Another method I have tried is to compute this by using integral by parts. Thus, the kernel will be $(t_m-s)^{1-\beta}/(1-\beta)$, which is without singularity. This method is valid when $f(s)$ have a good regularity, say in $C^1$. But when $f(s)$ does not have a continuous derivative, such as $|s|$ or Heaviside function, this method is also invalid.

What is more, $(t_m-s)^{-\beta}$ is only one kind of weakly singular kernel. How about other situations? Is there any general method to conquer this problem?

Comment: This won't help much, but many quadrature formulas do not involve evaluation at the end point of integration.

Comment: @BillBarth Yes. But the classical quadrature will loss precision when use them in this case.

Comment: What is your desired precision?  Is there anything you can say more about the families of $f(x)$ that are being used.  I am thinking it might be easier to rearrange things with some integration by parts, then treat the discontinuities in $f(x)$ separately.

Comment: This is what Gauss-Jacobi quadrature is for, though as meawoppl says you'll get better results if you use more of the structure of f: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Jacobi_quadrature

Comment: @meawoppl Thank you for your advice! That is a good idea to deal with the integral separately. In my work, $f(x)$ denotes the RHS of the PDE. So I think $f(x)\in H^1$. But in MATLAB implement, it is seems too tedious to let the program find the discontinuous points and compute the quadrature separately especially when $f(x)$ have too many discontinuous points. Anyway, your advice have enlighten me! Thank you very much!

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving This just the method I need! I have found some references about numerical analysis, but I do not see this method. Maybe I need to pay more attention on wikipedia from now on. I will try to implement this method. I think my problem have been solved. Thank you for your advice!